# Proper Schema.org markup for a big article with a question and related topics?

Tags: schema.org

I want to markup some article pages on a corporate site with Schema.org.  Articles have about 3000 - 5000 words and some of them focuse on a question and its answer.

A typical question could be like "What is religious faith?" Its answer comprehends some related topics like "christianity", "spiritutuality" etc. At the end of the article there is a summary which gives a shorter answer.

How to connect the article item with its topics by using the properties `about` and `mainEntity`? I'd like to express that the article has its focus on a certain question/answer but also markup some understandable and recognizable topics like "spirituality".

Is it o.k. to use both, `about` and `mainEntity`, on the same level, side by side, though `mainEntity` is a sub-property of `about`? 
Then it would look like this:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Article",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "https://example.com/article"
  },
  "mainEntity": {
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": "What is religious faith?",
    "text": "(longer version of the question)",
    "acceptedAnswer": {
       "@type": "Answer",
       "text": "(summary of the article)",
       "author": {
          "@type": "Person",
          "name": "(my own name)"
       }
    }
  },
  "about": [
  {
   "@type": "Thing",
   "name": "Spirituality",
   "sameAs": "(Wikipedia-URL)"
         },
  {        
   "@type": "Thing",
   "name": "Christianity",
   "sameAs": "(Wikipedia-URL)"
         }
       ],
  "author": "(my name)"
  }
```

Comment: Are the question and the answer from the same author? If yes, do they look like a regular article (one long body of text), or is the question designed in a way that it visually differs from the answer (e.g., like on this site here)?

Comment: Yes, question and answer is from the same author and it's a regular article. I don't want to get special QAPage-features of Google, schema code just should make clear that the whole article is about a central question. And as I will use article markup anyways I ask myself how I could accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think your structure is wrong, but I would suggest not to use `Question`/`Answer` (and thus also not `mainEntity`) within your articles.

I would argue there is no semantically relevant difference between an article that starts with "What is religious faith?" and an article that starts with "Let’s talk about religious faith" or something like that. It seems to be just a stylistic choice in your case, which is not the case for Q&A, support forum thread, or FAQ pages, where `Question` makes sense.

If each article is published on its own page, you could use the more specific [`ItemPage`](https://schema.org/ItemPage) (instead of `WebPage`). And for the topics the article is about, you could (at least in the cases of your example) use the more specific [`Intangible`](https://schema.org/Intangible) (instead of `Thing`).

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Article",

  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "ItemPage",
    "@id": "https://example.com/article"
  },

  "name": "What is religious faith?",
  "articleBody": "",
  "author": "(my name)",

  "about": [
    {
      "@type": "Intangible",
      "name": "Spirituality",
      "sameAs": "(Wikipedia-URL)"
    },
    {        
      "@type": "Intangible",
      "name": "Christianity",
      "sameAs": "(Wikipedia-URL)"
    }
  ]

}
```

Comment: I think it's more than just a stylistic choice. I mean, the article is really about this question and actually answers it comprehensivly, talking about different aspects and factors. It's not just like using a better sounding synonyme for "About religion faith". It's similar to all "What is"-questions, which are in a way definitions.